# JFrame repaint isuse

Tags: java, swing, repaint

```
/* DigitalGridActionListener.java
 * This class defines the Action Listener for the 'Digitzed Molecular Canvas'.
 * Whenever this class is initiated, a grid is drawn onto the screen
 * on which the user can start drawing.
 * The drawing is to be performed by simple clicking on the
 * on the grid boxes.
 * The user can also deselect a box by clicking on it again.
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DigitalGridActionListener implements ActionListener {

    static DrawCanvas canvas;
    static Graphics2D graphics2D;

    // Set Default Save Flags
    static boolean isToBeSaved = false;
    static boolean savedFunctionCalled = false;

    static JDialog jDialog = new JDialog();
    static double brickHeight = 3; // Set default Brick Height
    static double brickWidth = 7; // Set default Brick Width
    static ArrayList<XYCoordinates> xyCoordinatesBrickList = new ArrayList<XYCoordinates>();
    static DrawDataStack digitizedDataStack = new DrawDataStack();
    static boolean[][] gridValueAddedArray = new boolean[15][23];

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!MainFrame.newBrickCreated) {
            MainFrame.dnaBrick = new DNABrick(brickHeight, brickWidth);
            MainFrame.newBrickCreated = true;
        }

        if (MainFrame.currentWindow == 3) {
            canvas.setVisible(false);
            xyCoordinatesBrickList.clear();
            digitizedDataStack.clearData();
            isToBeSaved = false;
            MainFrame.newBrickCreated = false;
            MainFrame.panelLeft.remove(0);
        }

        /* This area checks if you're coming from the Free Hand Molecular Canvas
         * If yes, then it will give a pop-up to save any unsaved Draw Data
         */
        if (MainFrame.currentWindow == 2) {
            if (FreeGridActionListener.isToBeSaved && !FreeGridActionListener.savedFunctionCalled) {
                Object[] options = {"Yes",
                        "No",
                        "Cancel"};

                int userChoice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                        "Would you like to save the DNA Seq before leaving?",
                        "Save Resource",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        options,
                        options[2]);

                if (userChoice == 0) {  // Yes
                    JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();

                    int returnVal = jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
                    File file = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
                    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                        if(MainFrame.currentWindow == 2) {
                            try {
                                FreeGridActionListener.isToBeSaved = false;
                                ArrayList<Integer> xCoordinateList = FreeGridActionListener.xCoordinateBrickList;
                                ArrayList<Integer> yCoordinateList = FreeGridActionListener.yCoordinateBrickList;
                                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".csv"));
                                writeHeadersCanvas(bufferedWriter, xCoordinateList.size());

                                bufferedWriter.write("\n\nDraw Sequence Coordinates\n\n");

                                for (int i = 0; i < xCoordinateList.size(); i++) {
                                    bufferedWriter.write("Brick Number: " + (i + 1));
                                    bufferedWriter.write(",");
                                    bufferedWriter.write("X Coordinate: " + xCoordinateList.get(i));
                                    bufferedWriter.write(",");
                                    bufferedWriter.write("Y Coordinate: " + yCoordinateList.get(i) + "\n");
                                }

                                bufferedWriter.write("\n\nDNA Brick Sequence\n\n");
                                bufferedWriter.write(MainFrame.dnaBrick.toString());

                                bufferedWriter.write("\n\n Generated using DNA Pen. (http://www.guptalab.org/dnapen/)");
                                bufferedWriter.close();
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Saved Successfully !",
                                        "Success!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                                FreeGridActionListener.savedFunctionCalled = true;
                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The File could not be Saved!",
                                        "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (userChoice == 2) {  // Cancel
                    return;
                }
            }
            // Reset and clear Free Hand Molecular Canvas from the screen.
            FreeGridActionListener.canvas.setVisible(false);
            FreeGridActionListener.xCoordinateBrickList.clear();
            FreeGridActionListener.yCoordinateBrickList.clear();
            FreeGridActionListener.isToBeSaved = false;
            MainFrame.newBrickCreated = false;
            MainFrame.panelLeft.remove(0);
        }

        // Set value of currentWindow to 3 to indicate that Digital Molecular Canvas is active.
        MainFrame.currentWindow = 3;
        MainFrame.mainFrame.setTitle("DNA Pen - Digitised Molecular Canvas");
        MainFrame.mainFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        // Define the Canvas and the Output Box
         JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        MainFrame.panelLeft.add(jPanel);
        jPanel.setSize(1366, 700);
        jPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        canvas = new DrawCanvas();
        jPanel.add(canvas);
        canvas.setVisible(true);

       MainFrame.mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

           @Override
           public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
               System.out.println("\nOpened");
           }

           @Override
           public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
               System.out.println("\nMinimed");
          //     jPanel.setVisible(false);
           }

           @Override
           public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
               System.out.println("\nMaximized");
         //      jPanel.setVisible(true);
           }

           @Override
           public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
               System.out.println("\nActivated");
           //    jPanel.setVisible(true);

           }
       });

       // MainFrame.panelLeft.add(jPanel);
       // MainFrame.mainFrame.pack();
    }

    // Draw Method

    public class DrawCanvas extends Canvas {
        BasicStroke basicStroke;
        int X, Y, pressed = 0;
        float dashes[] = { 5f, 5f };

        public DrawCanvas() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 23; j++) {
                    gridValueAddedArray[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
            xyCoordinatesBrickList.clear();
            digitizedDataStack.clearData();

            setBackground(Color.white);
            addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
            addMouseMotionListener(new MyMouseListener());
            setSize(1366, 680);
            basicStroke = new BasicStroke(1f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                    BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 10f, dashes, 0f);
        }

        @Override
        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paint(g);
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            graphics2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            if(pressed == 1) {
                graphics2D.setColor(Color.black);
                graphics2D.setStroke(basicStroke);

                System.out.println(X - (X % 90));
                System.out.println(Y - (Y % 30));

                if (!gridValueAddedArray[X / 90][Y / 30]) {
                    fillElement(X, Y);
                } else {
                    removeElement(X, Y);
                }
            } else if (pressed == 2) {
                graphics2D.setColor(Color.white);
                graphics2D.fillRect(0, 0, 1366, 680);

                for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 23; j++) {
                        gridValueAddedArray[i][j] = false;
                    }
                }
                xyCoordinatesBrickList.clear();
                digitizedDataStack.clearData();

                int constY = 0;
                int constX = 0;
                graphics2D.setColor(Color.black);

                while (constY < 680) {
                    graphics2D.draw(new Line2D.Float(0, constY, 1366, constY));
                    constY += 30;
                }
                while (constX < 1366) {
                    graphics2D.draw(new Line2D.Float(constX, 0, constX, 680));
                    constX += 90;
                }
            } else if (pressed == 4) {
                XYCoordinates xyCoordinates = DigitalGridActionListener.digitizedDataStack.popData();
                int X = xyCoordinates.getxCoordinate();
                int Y = xyCoordinates.getyCoordinate();

                undoAction(X, Y);
            } else {
                int constY = 0;
                int constX = 0;
                while (constY < 680) {
                    graphics2D.draw(new Line2D.Float(0, constY, 1366, constY));
                    constY += 30;
                }
                while (constX < 1366) {
                    graphics2D.draw(new Line2D.Float(constX, 0, constX, 680));
                    constX += 90;
                }
            }
        }

        public void undoAction(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate) {
            int constY = 0;
            int constX = 0;
            while (constY < 680) {
                graphics2D.draw(new Line2D.Float(0, constY, 1366, constY));
                constY += 30;
            }
            while (constX < 1366) {
                graphics2D.draw(new Line2D.Float(constX, 0, constX, 680));
                constX += 90;
            }

            System.out.println("\n" + (xCoordinate - (xCoordinate % 90)));
            System.out.println("\n" + (yCoordinate - (yCoordinate % 30)));

            System.out.println("\nUndo How Many Times");

            graphics2D.setColor(Color.white);
            graphics2D.fillRect(xCoordinate - (xCoordinate % 90), yCoordinate - (yCoordinate % 30), 90, 30);
            gridValueAddedArray[xCoordinate / 90][yCoordinate / 30] = false;

            int xValue = 0;
            int yValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < xyCoordinatesBrickList.size(); i++) {
                xValue = xyCoordinatesBrickList.get(i).getxCoordinate();
                yValue = xyCoordinatesBrickList.get(i).getyCoordinate();

                if (xValue == (xCoordinate / 90) && yValue == (yCoordinate / 30)) {
                    xyCoordinatesBrickList.remove(i);
                }
            }
            pressed = 0;
        }

        public void fillElement(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate) {
            graphics2D.setColor(Color.lightGray);
            graphics2D.fillRect(xCoordinate - (xCoordinate % 90), yCoordinate - (yCoordinate % 30), 90, 30);
            gridValueAddedArray[xCoordinate / 90][yCoordinate / 30] = true;
            xyCoordinatesBrickList.add(new XYCoordinates(xCoordinate / 90, yCoordinate / 30));
            digitizedDataStack.pushData(new XYCoordinates(xCoordinate, yCoordinate));
        }

        public void removeElement(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate) {
            graphics2D.setColor(Color.white);
            graphics2D.fillRect(xCoordinate - (xCoordinate % 90), yCoordinate - (yCoordinate % 30), 90, 30);
            gridValueAddedArray[xCoordinate / 90][yCoordinate / 30] = false;
            digitizedDataStack.removeSpecificElement(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);

            int xValue = 0;
            int yValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < xyCoordinatesBrickList.size(); i++) {
                xValue = xyCoordinatesBrickList.get(i).getxCoordinate();
                yValue = xyCoordinatesBrickList.get(i).getyCoordinate();

                if (xValue == (xCoordinate / 90) && yValue == (yCoordinate / 30)) {
                    xyCoordinatesBrickList.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }

        class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener {

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                isToBeSaved = true;
                savedFunctionCalled = false;
                pressed = 1;
                X = e.getX();
                Y = e.getY();

               canvas.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                pressed = 0;
                canvas.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                canvas.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                String string = "(" + Integer.toString(e.getX()) + ", "
                        + Integer.toString(e.getY()) + ")";
                canvas.repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    public void writeHeadersCanvas(BufferedWriter bufferedWriter, int listSize) {
        try {
            double brickHeight = MainFrame.dnaBrick.getBrickHeight();
            double brickWidth = MainFrame.dnaBrick.getBrickWidth();
            int minWidth = (int)(brickWidth / 1.75);
            int minHeight = (int)(brickHeight / .6);
            int[] halfTiles = calcHalfTiles(brickHeight, brickWidth);
            int fullTiles = calcFullTiles(brickHeight, brickWidth);
            int stickyEnds = calcStickyEnds(brickHeight, brickWidth);
            int totalNumberSeq = calcTotalNumberSeq(halfTiles, fullTiles, stickyEnds);
            DNADomains dnaDomains = MainFrame.dnaBrick.getDnaDomains();

            bufferedWriter.write("Base DNA Sequence: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");

            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqOne() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqTwo() +
                    dnaDomains.getDomainSeqThree() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqFour() + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Domain Sequence 1: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqOne() + "\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Domain Sequence 2: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqTwo() + "\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Domain Sequence 3: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqThree() + "\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Domain Sequence 4: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqFour() + "\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Brick Height: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(Double.toString(brickHeight) + " nm" + "\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Brick Width: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(Double.toString(brickWidth) + " nm" + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Total Number of Bricks: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(listSize + "\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Number of Base DNA Sequences Required: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(totalNumberSeq * listSize + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Half-Tile Sequence of Domain 1 and Domain 2: ( L1.1 - L1." + minWidth +
                    " )" );
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqOne() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqTwo() + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("Required number of Half-Tiles: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write((halfTiles[0] / 2) + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Half-Tile Sequence of Domain 3 and Domain 4: ( L" + (minHeight + 1) + ".1 - L"
                    + (minHeight + 1) + "." + minWidth + " )");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqThree() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqFour() + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("Required number of Half-Tiles: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write((halfTiles[0] / 2) + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Half-Tile Sequence of Domain 2 and Domain 3: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqTwo() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqThree() + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("Required number of Half-Tiles: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write((halfTiles[1] / 2) * listSize + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Half-Tile Sequence of Domain 1 and Domain 4: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqOne() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqFour() + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("Required number of Half-Tiles: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write((halfTiles[1] / 2) * listSize + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Full-Tile Sequence: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqOne() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqTwo() +
                    dnaDomains.getDomainSeqThree() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqFour() + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("Required number of Full-Tiles: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(fullTiles * listSize + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Sticky-End Sequence of Domain 1 and Domain 4: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqOne() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqFour() + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("Required number of Sticky Ends: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write((stickyEnds / 2) * listSize + "\n\n");

            bufferedWriter.write("Sticky-End Sequence of Domain 2 and Domain 3: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write(dnaDomains.getDomainSeqTwo() + dnaDomains.getDomainSeqThree() + "\n");
            bufferedWriter.write("Required number of Sticky Ends: ");
            bufferedWriter.write(",");
            bufferedWriter.write((stickyEnds / 2) * listSize + "\n\n");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exception Occurred !",
                    "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    public int[] calcHalfTiles(double brickHeight, double brickWidth) {
        int[] halfTiles = new int[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < halfTiles.length; i++) {
            halfTiles[i] = 0;
        }

        halfTiles[0] += 2 * (brickWidth / 1.75);
        halfTiles[1] += 2 * Math.ceil(brickHeight / 1.2);

        return halfTiles;
    }

    public int calcFullTiles(double brickHeight, double brickWidth) {
        int fullTiles = 0;

        int oddRows = (int) Math.ceil(brickHeight / 1.2);
        int evenRows = (int)(brickHeight / 0.6) - oddRows;

        fullTiles += oddRows * ((brickWidth / 1.75) - 1);
        fullTiles += evenRows * (brickWidth /1.75);

        return fullTiles;
    }

    public int calcStickyEnds(double brickHeight, double brickWidth) {
        int stickyEnds = 0;

        stickyEnds += 2 * Math.ceil(brickHeight / 1.2);

        return stickyEnds;
    }

    public int calcTotalNumberSeq(int[] halfTiles, int fullTiles, int stickyEnds) {
        int totalNumberSeq = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < halfTiles.length; i++) {
            totalNumberSeq += halfTiles[i];
        }

        totalNumberSeq = totalNumberSeq / 2;
        totalNumberSeq += fullTiles;
        totalNumberSeq += stickyEnds / 2;

        return totalNumberSeq;
    }
}
```

Whenever I minimize the window , the data on canvas is cleaned and returns me empty canvas... how to save the state while minimizing the window ... I tried to repaint on mouse listener but it didn't work

Comment: So you just dump your 504 lines of code here and expect us to look through ALL 504 lines for free?

Comment: For better help & sooner, post a **Short**, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Huh!  Over 500 LOC and it *still* has 38 compilation errors for missing classes.  Good luck getting help with that.  I 2nd @Reimeus call for an SSCCE.

Comment: As an aside.  Try drawing the ..whatever it is, to a `BufferedImage` and displaying that in a `JLabel`.  The drawings in the image will definitely survive being minimized and restored.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use AWT components in a Swing application.

Use a JPanel not a Canvas. Override `paintComponent()` of the panel and don't override update().

Invoke super.paintComponent() when you override the paintComponent() method.

Don't override paint() on a JFrame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

Comment: thnx for your help, I working on the thing you explained above.

Comment: @DoorKnob No body asked for your free help